# fit an ellipse through points

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Using opencv for python I need to fit an ellipse (using cv2.fitEllipse) to the array of points returned by cv.FindCornerSubPix (here named 'features'). I have seen numerous examples of this on the internet, but I cannot figure it out.
I figured cv.FindCornerSubPix returns an array of tuples, and my code triggered an error asking me for a numpy array as argument for cv2.fitEllipse, so I tried to convert 'features' to a numpy array and the error is now:

'error: ......\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:2019: error: (-215) points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S)'

on line 196 ('cv2.fitEllipse(ellipse)' at the end of my code), so I guess I am not feeding the right array format to cv2.fitEllipse. Would you please help me? The code below is just a modified version of the opencv sample lkdemo.py.

```
            # search the good points
        features = cv.GoodFeaturesToTrack (
            grey, eig, temp,
            MAX_COUNT,
            quality, min_distance, mask, 10, 0, 0.04)

        # refine the corner locations
        features = cv.FindCornerSubPix (
            grey,
            features,
            (win_size, win_size),  (-1, -1),
            (cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.03))

    elif features != []:
        # we have points, so display them

        # calculate the optical flow
        features, status, track_error = cv.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK (
            prev_grey, grey, prev_pyramid, pyramid,
            features,
            (win_size, win_size), 3,
            (cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.03),
            flags)

        # set back the points we keep
        features = [ p for (st,p) in zip(status, features) if st]

        if add_remove_pt:
            # we have a point to add, so see if it is close to
            # another one. If yes, don't use it
            def ptptdist(p0, p1):
                dx = p0[0] - p1[0]
                dy = p0[1] - p1[1]
                return dx**2 + dy**2
            if min([ ptptdist(pt, p) for p in features ]) < 25:
                # too close
                add_remove_pt = 0

        # draw the points as green circles
        for the_point in features:
            cv.Circle (image, (int(the_point[0]), int(the_point[1])), 3, (0, 255, 0, 0), -1, 8, 0)

        #Fit an ellipse
        array = np.array([tuple(i) for i in features])
        ellipse = np.asarray(array)
        cv2.fitEllipse(ellipse)
```

Comment: Solved it:

    #Fit an ellipse
            feature_matrix = cv.CreateMat(1, len(features), cv2.CV_32SC2)
            i = 0
            for the_point in features:
                cv.Set2D(feature_matrix, 0, i, (int(the_point[0]), int(the_point[1])))
                i = i + 1
            if len(features) > 6:
                feature_matrix = np.asarray(feature_matrix)
                ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(feature_matrix)
                image = np.asarray(image[:,:])
                cv2.ellipse(image,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
                image = cv.fromarray(image[:,:])

Comment: Please post your comment as answer and accept it, that way anyone can see it's already solved. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved. Please look in the comments section. By the way, Stackoverflow asks for a delay of several hours for a newcomer to answer his own questions, which is why I put the answer in the comments.

Cheers